# Installing Qt not working

Tags: c++, qt

Is Qt still free? When i try to download it, it keeps asking to buy it and credit card number... After some time I managed to find free download at 

but when I try to install, it just stucks around 50%, after 10 minutes I canceled download. 
I don't understand, is it free or do I have to buy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is released according to a multi-licensing model. You can freely use it keeping your code proprietary as long as you respect the LGPL license:

- You do not modify the code of the Qt libraries
- You dynamically link the library (i.e. no static linking)
- You give people who will receive the binary under *any* form the possibility of re-linking your (commercial) object file to a different version of Qt. In practice, this means that you have to provide your object file and the instructions/tools for linking.
- In case of Qt components under LGPLv3 you have some additional constraints with respect to LGPLv2. The most important is that you cannot use "tivoization" (hardware techniques that prevent the user from running the new binary resulting from re-linking as above).

Answer (score 0):

It is still free, but when you open the installer, Qt will ask for a Login or asks you to Sign-up. However, there is a "Skip" button below that you can use.

Sometimes, the online-installer may have trouble downloading all files, that is probably just a one-time issue. You can also download the offline-installers, the latest you can find at: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2

The online-installer however comes with a "Maintenance Tool" which can easily update existing Qt software to newer version (e.g. update 5.6 to 5.6.1 when it is released). Download-problems aside, I personally prefer the online-installer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this one-time issues for 3 weeks nows. The online installer takes hours to complete, if at all. As Frank mentioned check at https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/ which seems to offer the offline packages. I'll see if that works.